# Draw transparent text on canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw, transparent

I am trying to write a semi-transparent text on a canvas. I see the string written on the canvas but the transparency doesn't seem to work. Here's my code:

```
     public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
    paint.setAlpha(1);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setTextSize(this.textSize);
    paint.setColor(textColor);
    canvas.drawText(text,x,y,paint); 
    Logs.add("onDraw DefaultScoreGottenText currentAlpha = " + this.currentAlpha);
    showAnimation(null);
}
```

The alpha property is set but doesn't seem to have any effects. I even try to create a new Paint object and send it to the drawText method. Didn't work either. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

paint.setColor() includes alpha, so when you call paint.setColor(textColor) you are overwriting the alpha that you set in paint.setAlpha(1).  Try setting the alpha and text color at the same time with:

```
paint.setColor(Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue));
```

Answer (score 3):

Or just set the alpha **below** the color.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I had exactly the same issue. The simple way to solve is to set the alpha below the color, not above. I post this because it will help people that have this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You are overriding alpha by setting color value. so just set alpha after setting your color

```
paint.setColor(textColor);
paint.setAlpha(1);
```

note that alpha takes a value between 0 and 255

Comment: xml android:alpha attribute is 0 - 1f, so this lead me to misunderstand, you save my day thx.

Answer (score 0):

Set color #00112233

here 00 is transparent

11 is red value

22 is green value

33 is blue value

if you change the first two digit in between 00 to FF , you can see the transparent variation.